# How can I implement a percentage chance to perform some action?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say that there is an X% chance that a character will shoot a target, or some other action. How do I determine if the action should be taken or not (how do I implement the percentage chance)?

Comment: Please check these related questions to ensure your question is not already answered: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54551/using-random-numbers-with-a-bias http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32992/practical-balance-of-chance-video-game-mechanics http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59543/how-do-i-apply-different-probability-factors-in-an-algorithm-for-a-cricket-simul http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/how-to-get-the-result-of-random-item-with-different-possibility

Comment: This question seems to be more fitting for a programming se.

Comment: Note it currently asks a question that seems focussed on a different type of random generation (a multiple decision system) which is again quite different from this one.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is, take a pseudo random generator and let it generate a float between 0 and 1. You would then multiply it with 100 to get into the range of 0 to 100. If this final value is smaller than the percent of the chance, in this example, the tank would hit the target. Here is some pseudo code, what it could look like:

```
// chance of tank, hitting the target
float chance = 70.0f;

// first, generate a pseudo random float in the range of 0 to 1
float n = random();

// multiply n with 100 to get into the range of 0 to 100
n = n * 100;

// if n is below chance, the tank will hit the target
if(n < chance)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Edit: Changed from int to float, due to the fact that Anko mentioned.

Comment: The modulo operator is often a really bad idea with random numbers. The maximum integer produced by `random` is in most cases not a multiple of 100, causing a biased output: Imagine if the maximum integer was 150. Everything from 0-100 would `% 100` to the range 0-100. Everything from 101 to 150 would mod to 1-50. That means outputs 0-50 are much more likely! Instead, have your RNG generate a float and do `if (randomFloat() * 100 < chance) { ... }`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't thought about that. I will edit my answer.